# Is it possible to trigger (integration) test project after MS Deploy in TFS Build server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I would like to run all the tests in my integration/UI test project (Selenium) as part of the continuous integration process (execute website automation tests on the development environment, not localhost)

The current process is `Build > Run Unit Tests > DeployOnBuild`, and I would like to add the `Execute integration tests` step triggered after successful deployment, and the output of these tests displayed somewhere on the build results summary.

Is it all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize the template to add the **Integration Tests** to TFS Build Workflow.

Please refer to below link for more details:

https://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/adding-integration-tests-to-tfs-build-workflow/

---

Another two articles may help you:

- [Automated Build-Deploy-Test using TFS 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2011/10/17/automated-build-deploy-test-using-tfs-2010/)
- [Continuous Integration, Continuous Deployment with Team Foundation
  Server 2013 & VS 2013 Update 2](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1050/visual-studio-continuous-integration-deployment)

Comment: @Bartosz Have you resolved the issue by this workaround?